# How prove this statement?

Tags: relations

1. A transitive and connected relation is a negative transitive?
2. A negative transitive and asymmetric relation is transitive?

Is this correct for 2?
Assume that R be transitive and connected relation but is not a transitive
(if $(a,b) \in R$ and $(b,c)\in R$ we have not $(a,c)\in R$).
So for every a,b:

$(a,b) \notin R$ from connected $(b,a)\in R$,

$(b,c) \notin R$ from connected $(c,b)\in R$.

From above and transitive we have $(c,a)\in R$ . what should I do next?

How can I show 1 is true?

Comment: In the problem statement for 2, you say negative transitive and asymmetric, but in the proof you use negative transitive and connected. Which is it? As for 1, consider the _trivial relation_, i.e. the relation where every single available pair is an element.

Comment: @Arthur  hello, You're right, I changed it.  Thank you